# How to disable current year in Bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: jquery

How to disable current year in Bootstrap datepicker?

```
$('#date_of_birth').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        endDate: '+0d',
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    });
```

Comment: You need to put some effort into explaining what you are trying to do.  The question is currently far too ambiguous.

Comment: do you wan't to make a datepicker with only day and month !?

Comment: no, I just want only disable the current year in the calendar

Comment: Are you saying that you want to force the user to select a different year?  If so, in the past, future or both?  You need to explain.  Saying the same thing again does not help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the end date so for disabling the current year you can set something like this,so the calendar dates will be visible upto 2016.It is that what you want?

```
var maxDate = new Date("2017-01-01");
$('.date').datepicker('setEndDate', maxDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var maxDate = new Date();
var pastYear = maxDate.getFullYear() - 1;
maxDate.setFullYear(pastYear);
maxDate.setMonth(11);
maxDate.setDate(31);

$('#drivers-dob').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    //endDate: '+0d',
    endDate: maxDate,
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
});
```

Comment: To improve your answer you should add a description text about your solution

Comment: It's good to hear that you found the cause of your problem.  You could make your answer more helpful for future readers by explaining *how* you diagnosed it, and in particular, which evidence will identify this problem when it's seen elsewhere.